# Правильный оператор для процедуры

Tags: sql

Задача состоит в том, что нужно сделать процедуру - Выдать книгу читателю по ее ID. Если читателя нет в базе данных – добавить его автоматически.
Сделал проверку оператором IF-else, а нужно чтобы - проверка, если нет то перейти дальше, если да то выполнить вставку и перейти дальше.
Получилось только, что оно работает только вставку в таблицу READER, если читателя нет, а else не срабатывает .
Какой лучше оператор или цикл использовать ??

```
Create PROC myProc
    @l_name VARCHAR(30),
    @f_name VARCHAR(30),
    @id_book INT,
    @reader_id INT = @@IDENTITY
    AS 
SELECT reader_id = READER.reader_id FROM READER 
WHERE READER.last_name = @l_name AND READER.first_name = @f_name
IF (@reader_id IS NULL)
    INSERT INTO READER VALUES(@l_name, @f_name, 'Khmelnitsky', '01/05/1996', 0967253257, 0, 1490);
ELSE
INSERT INTO BOOK_GIVING VALUES(@id_book, @@IDENTITY, '02/08/2014', '22/08/2014', '22/09/2014');

EXEC myProc 'test30', 'test40', 3;
```

Если ДА, то вставить в READER , перейти и вставить в BOOK_GIVING 
Если НЕТ, то пропустить вставку в READER , перейти и вставить в BOOK_GIVING
Вот так думаю более понятно

Comment: Вам же в giving надо всегда вставлять. Вот и вставляйте всегда, просто по окончании IF, никаких else не надо